# "cu" for "see you", "ic" for "I see" - what do you call those?

Tags: abbreviations, acronyms, initialisms

What do you call the sequences of letters that produce phrases when read letter by letter? Examples include "CU" for "see you", "IC" for "I see" and so on.

Comment: Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language) for the various terms being used in textese.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I wasn't looking for the terms themselves but for the collective name. Speaking of which "textese" sounds pretty close, so thank you!

Comment: Textese includes other shortened forms (eg lol) as well as the 'letter for similar sounding word' ones you specify. There are even pictograms. You probably want 'logograms'.

Comment: You would see such things occasionally before the days of texting or the Internet.  In fact, I recall a whole book of cartoons with such captions.  *IMNDLF8R* and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we may tend to think of an [abbreviation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abbreviation) as a shortening to the first part of a word (*abbrev* for *abbreviation*), it can be defined as

> a shortened form of a written word or phrase used in place of the
>   whole

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation) has this to say about "Textese" in particular:

> Widespread use of electronic communication through mobile phones and
>   the Internet during the 1990s allowed for a marked rise in colloquial
>   abbreviation. [...] SMS, for instance, supports message lengths of 160 characters at most [...]. This brevity gave rise to an informal abbreviation scheme sometimes called Textese, with which 10% or more of the words in a typical SMS message are abbreviated.

Of course, there are many types of abbreviations, but, broadly speaking, "txtpsk" is an abbreviating act.

Comment: i h8 abrvi8shunz.

Comment: I also am not too fond of them, Mr.

Comment: I'm more familiar with the name "textspeak" than "Textese", but otherwise this answer is about what I would have answered.

Comment: Yes, Wikipedia used "Textese" so I had to use it to say that's what was being discussed. I prefer "textspeak" ("txtspk"), so you'll see I threw it in there :) There are quite a number of different terms in use for it though.

Answer (score 0):

German Wikipedia calls them [Abbreviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation)s and [Acronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym)s as can be found here:
[Liste von Abkürzungen (Netzjargon)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Abk%C3%BCrzungen_%28Netzjargon%29). However, there is no corresponding article in English (at least now).

There are also Abbreviations called [Homophone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone), such as `ICQ ("I seek you")`.

Comment: Extrapolating from the German page there, it seems like "net jargon" or "netspeak" (or "chatspeak") might all apply.

Comment: They can be used in SMS messages too, thus it is not the "net jargon" only. Maybe, it seems more like abbreviations and acronyms of the 21st century or the digital age. (?) At least, because of their current popularity.

Answer (score 0):

Those are [logograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logogram). In the specific context of text messages (aka SMS), logograms and pictograms are often combined in the infamous [SMS language](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language). If combined with pictures or other non-alphanumeric elements, they become [rebuses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus).

Comment: Your link says "logograms are visual symbols representing words rather than the sounds or phonemes that make up the word", so I'm not sure that fits for the OP's specific examples ("CU" = the exact sounds of "see you").

Comment: Does that include "Thz R lggrmz. n th spsfc cntxt v txt msjs (aka SMz), lggrmz & pctgrmz R oftn cmbnd n th nfmz SMz lngj. f cmbnd wth pctrs o othr nn-alfnmrc elmnts, thy bcm rbss." as well?